# Improve efficiency of Harris Corner Detector

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision, edge-detection

I built this Harris Corner Detector which works exactly as it's expected in terms of functionality however when it comes to performance it is extremely slow. I am almost sure that it has to do with the fact that I'm accessing every pixel of the image but it might also be that I'm implementing something wrong. I've been thinking of how to optimize np array access for applying the filters but because of the nature of these filters I still can't come up with a good idea. 
The method is not slow by itself as with OpenCV is basically instant for the same image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import math


def hor_edge_strength(x, y, img_in = [], filter = []):
strength = 0
for i in range (0,3):
    for j in range (0,3):
        strength += img_in[x+i-1][y+j-1] * filter[i][j]
return strength


def ver_edge_strength(x, y, img_in = [], filter = []):
strength = 0
for i in range (0,3):
    for j in range (0,3):
        strength += img_in[x+i-1][y+j-1] * filter[i][j]
return strength

def gauss_kernels(size,sigma=1):
## returns a 2d gaussian kernel
if size<3:
    size = 3
m = size/2
x, y = np.mgrid[-m:m+1, -m:m+1]
kernel = np.exp(-(x*x + y*y)/(2*sigma*sigma))
kernel_sum = kernel.sum()
if not sum==0:
    kernel = kernel/kernel_sum
return kernel

sobel_h = [[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
sobel_v = [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]]

img_arr = ['checker.jpg'] #Test image
for img_name in img_arr:
img = cv.imread(img_name,0)
sep = '.'
img_name = img_name.split(sep, 1)[0]
print img_name
gray_img = img.astype(float)
gx = np.zeros_like(gray_img)
gy = np.zeros_like(gray_img)

print 'Getting strengths'
for i in range(1, len(gray_img) - 1):
    for j in range(1, len(gray_img[0]) - 1):
        gx[i][j] = hor_edge_strength(i, j, gray_img, sobel_h) 
        gy[i][j] = ver_edge_strength(i, j, gray_img, sobel_v)
I_xx = gx * gx
I_xy = gx * gy
I_yy = gy * gy

gaussKernel = gauss_kernels(3,1)

W_xx = np.zeros_like(gray_img)
W_xy = np.zeros_like(gray_img)
W_yy = np.zeros_like(gray_img)

print 'Convoluting'
for i in range(1, len(gray_img) - 1):
    for j in range(1, len(gray_img[0]) - 1):
        W_xx[i][j] = hor_edge_strength(i, j, I_xx, gaussKernel) 
        W_xy[i][j] = hor_edge_strength(i, j, I_xy, gaussKernel)
        W_yy[i][j] = hor_edge_strength(i, j, I_yy, gaussKernel)

print 'Calculating Harris Corner'
k = 0.06
HCResponse = np.zeros_like(gray_img)
for i in range(1, len(gray_img) - 1):
    for j in range(1, len(gray_img[0]) - 1):
        W = np.matrix([[W_xx[i][j],W_xy[i][j]],[W_xy[i][j],W_yy[i][j]]]) #For lap purposes, but not needed
        detW = W_xx[i][j]*W_yy[i][j] - (W_xy[i][j] * W_xy[i][j])
        traceW = W_xx[i][j] + W_yy[i][j]
        HCResponse[i][j] = detW - k*traceW*traceW

threshold = 0.1
imageTreshold = max(HCResponse.ravel()) * threshold

HCResponseTreshold = (HCResponse >= imageTreshold) * 1
candidates = np.transpose(HCResponseTreshold.nonzero())

print 'Drawing'

x, y = gray_img.shape
image = np.empty((x, y, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
image[:, :, 0] = gray_img
image[:, :, 1] = gray_img
image[:, :, 2] = gray_img
for i in candidates:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    image[x][y] = [255,0,0]
pl.imshow(image)
pl.show()
pl.savefig(img_name + '_edge.jpg')
```

Is there any possible solution to substantially improve the performance of this edge detector?

Comment: take a look at [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'chess1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

for more info see this [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)